# Object-Oriented design - Spells

Tags: java, oop

I work on my first Java project, which is a basic roleplaying game. Now I work on spells, and I need some OOD guidance.

I have `Character`, which is an `abstract class`. `Character` has some `subclasses` (like `mage`, `fighter`, `rogue`, `cleric`).

`Mage` and `cleric`(as for `now`, cleric doesn't have *mana*, but it might change) are both spell-casters.

I also have a `Spell` class, with some info (like `spell name`, `mana cost` etc). `MageSpellsList` and `ClericSpellsList` are another classes and both have lists of class Spell. and I also have `Effects` class(casting a spell should use it).

What would be a good object oriented design for dealing with spells (the solution shouldn't include `Effects` class, I can deal with that later) ?

Maybe using a "SpellCaster" interface with some methods like castSpell and showSpellbook, so Mage and Cleric will implement the interface? .

Maybe MageSpellsList and ClericSpellsList should be a subclass of Spell ? My goal is to use castSpell("spell name here") and let castSpell do the job, by using a good OOD, rather than writing a specific method for each spell (and without duplicate code between mage and Cleric)

Mage.java:

```
public class Mage extends Character {

    private List<Spell> spellBook;
    private int mana;
    private int CurrentMana;

    public Mage(String name) {

        super(name);

        setName(name);
        setCharacterClass("Mage");
        setLevel(1);
        setHitDice(4);

        setStrength(10);
        setConstitution(10);
        setDexterity(14);
        setIntelligence(16);
        setWisdom(14);
        setCharisma(10);

        setHp((int) (4 + getModifier(getConstitution())));
        setCurrentHp(getHp());
        setArmorClass(10 + getModifier(getDexterity()));
        setBaseAttackBonus(0);

        setMana(20 + 2 * getModifier(getIntelligence()));
        setCurrentMana(getMana());
        spellBook = new ArrayList<Spell>();

    }

    public int getMana() {
        return mana;
    }

    public int getCurrentMana() {
        return CurrentMana;
    }

    protected void setMana(int mna) {
        mana = mna;
    }

    protected void setCurrentMana(int CurrMana) {
        CurrentMana = CurrMana;
    }

    public void showSpellBook() {

        for (Iterator<Spell> iter = spellBook.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
            Spell spell = iter.next();
            System.out.println("Spell name: " + spell.getSpellName());
            System.out.println("Spell effect: " + spell.getEffect());
        }
    }

    public void addToSpellBook(String spellName) {

        Spell newSpell;
        newSpell = MageSpellsList.getSpell(spellName);
        spellBook.add(newSpell);
        System.out.println(newSpell.getSpellName() + " has been added to the spellbook");

    }


    public void chooseSpells() {
        System.out.println();
    }

    void castSpell(String spellName, Character hero, Character target) {
        try {
            Spell spell = MageSpellsList.getSpell(spellName);
            System.out.println("You casted: " + spellName);
            System.out.println("Spell effect: " + spell.getEffect());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No such spell");
        }
    }
}
```

Spell.java:

```
public class Spell {
    private String name;
    private int spellLevel;
    private String effect;
    private int manaCost;
    private int duration;

    Spell(String name, int spellLevel, String effect, int manaCost, int duration) {
        this.name = name;
        this.spellLevel = spellLevel;
        this.effect = effect;
        this.manaCost = manaCost;
        this.duration= duration;
    }

    String getSpellName() { return name; }

    int getSpellLevel() { return spellLevel; }

    String getEffect() { return effect; }

    int getManaCost() {
        return manaCost;
    }

    int getDuration() { return  duration; }
}
```

MageSpellsList.java:

```
public class MageSpellsList {
    static List<Spell> MageSpellsList = new ArrayList<Spell>();

    static {
        MageSpellsList.add(new Spell("Magic Missiles", 1, "damage", 2, 0));
        MageSpellsList.add(new Spell("Magic Armor", 1, "changeStat", 2, 0));
        MageSpellsList.add(new Spell("Scorching Ray ", 2, "damage", 4, 0));
        MageSpellsList.add(new Spell("Fireball", 3, "damage", 5,0 ));
        MageSpellsList.add(new Spell("Ice Storm", 4, "damage", 8, 0));
    }

    static void  showSpellsOfLevel(int spellLevel) {
        try {
            for (Iterator<Spell> iter = MageSpellsList.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
                Spell spell = iter.next();
                if (spellLevel == spell.getSpellLevel()) {
                    System.out.println("Spell name: " + spell.getSpellName());
                    System.out.println("Spell effect: " + spell.getEffect());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Epells of level " + spellLevel + " haven't been found in spells-list");
        }
    }

    static Spell getSpell(String spellName) {
        try {
            for (Iterator<Spell> iter = MageSpellsList.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
                Spell spell = iter.next();
                if (spellName.equals(spell.getSpellName())) {
                    return spell;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(spellName + " haven't been found in spells-list");
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Effects.java:

```
public class Effects {

    public  void  damage(int dice, Character attacker, Character target){

        int damage = DiceRoller.roll(dice);
        System.out.println(attacker.getName() + " dealt " + damage + " damage to " + target.getName());
        target.setCurrentHp(target.getCurrentHp() - damage);
    }

    public static void damage(int n, int dice, int bonus, Character target) {

        int damage = DiceRoller.roll(n,dice,bonus);
        System.out.println("You dealt" + damage + "damage to " + target.getName());
        target.setCurrentHp(target.getCurrentHp() - damage);
    }

    public static void heal(int n, int dice, int bonus, Character target) {

        int heal = DiceRoller.roll(n,dice,bonus);
        if (heal + target.getCurrentHp() >= target.getHp()) {
            target.setCurrentHp(target.getHp());
        } else {
            target.setCurrentHp(target.getCurrentHp() + heal);
        }

        System.out.println("You healed" + heal + " hit points!");
    }

    public static void changeStat(String stat, int mod, Character target){

        System.out.println(stat + " + " + mod);

        switch (stat) {
            case "strength":
                target.setStrength(target.getStrength() + mod);
                break;
            case "constitution":
                target.setConstitution(target.getConstitution() + mod);
                break;
            case "dexterity":
                target.setDexterity(target.getDexterity() + mod);
                break;
            case "intelligence":
                target.setIntelligence(target.getIntelligence() + mod);
                break;
            case "wisdom":
                target.setWisdom(target.getWisdom() + mod);
                break;
            case "charisma":
                target.setCharisma(target.getCharisma() + mod);
                break;
            case "armorClass":
                target.setArmorClass(target.getArmorClass() + mod);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Two suggestions:
1. Don't use `List` for spells here, use `Set`. `List` can have duplicates, `Set` cannnot. This is also why the class name `MageSpellsList` is probably not so good: it exposes implementation details (that you happen to be using a `List`). Maybe expose just `Collection`?
2. Define an `enum` containing the stats you have, and use that in e.g. `changeStat`.

Comment: By the way, you might want to rename your superclass `Character` to something else, since it collides with `java.lang.Character` :)

Comment: If `name` is passed to the constructor as an argument, you probably don't need to also call `setName(name)`?

Comment: 1. Yeah, a set is probably better in this case than list. 2. I'm not sure that enums will give me enough flexibility here.

Comment: Yeah, I know setName is redundant. Things will change here once I'm sure I have a better design. so I'm not worried about that at the moment.

Comment: Enums are essentially glorified (string) constants. The main advantage compared to just string constants is that they are full classes and can contain their own code, so they would normally be *more* flexible than string constants. I'll see if I can toss together an example for you!

Comment: I'd be glad for a good example. Anyway, Let's take damage spell for instance, it can get much further than just constants. The damage of "Scorching Rays" can be 3d6 for one scorching ray  + another scorching ray for 3 levels above level 3, with maximum amount of 3 rays in total , for instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Preamble

I try to generalise the classes as much as possible, so I do not end up with lots of specific classes that just represent different data, instead of a different structure. Also, I try to separate data structures from game mechanics. In particular, I try to keep the combat mechanics all in one place, instead of splitting them across different classes, and I try not to hard-code any data. In this answer, we will cover the **characters**, their **abilities/spells**, the **effects** of the abilities, and the **combat mechanics**.

### Characters

Consider, for instance, a `PlayableCharacter`, that represents your characters. This is a standard data class. It provides methods for increasing or decreasing health and mana, and a collection of available abilities.

```
class PlayableCharacter {
    private final int maxHealth;
    private int health;
    private final int maxResource;    // mana, energy and so on
    private int resource;
    private final Collection<Ability> abilities;

    // getters and setters
}
```

### Abilities

Abilities are equally data classes. They represent mana costs, triggered effects, and so on. I often represent this as a normal class, and then read the individual abilities from external data files. Here we can skip that and declare them with enumerations.

```
enum Ability {
    FIREBALL("Fireball", 3, 5, new Effect[] {
        new Effect(Mechanic.DAMAGE, 10, 0),
        new Effect(Mechanic.BURN, 2, 3)
    });

    private final String name;
    private final int level;
    private final int cost;
    private final List<Effect> effects;
}
```

### Effects

Finally the effects tell what an ability does. How much damage, how long it lasts, how it affects a character. Again, this is all data, no game logic.

```
class Effect {
    private final Mechanic effect;
    private final int value;
    private final int duration;
}
```

The mechanics are just an enumeration.

```
enum Mechanic {
    DAMAGE, BURN;
}
```

### Mechanics

Now it is time to make things work properly. This is the class that your game loop will be interacting with, and you must feed it the game state (which characters are battling, for instance).

```
class BattleEngine {
    void useAbility(PlayableCharacter source, PlayableCharacter target, Ability ability) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

How you implement each mechanic is up to you. It can range from an infernal switch or if/else for each `Mechanic`, or you can move the code to the `Mechanic` enum, or to private nested classes and use an `EnumMap` to retrieve each handler.

### Example Mechanic

```
interface MechanicHandler {
    void apply(PlayableCharacter source, PlayableCharacter target, Effect effect);
}
```

```
class BattleEngine {
    private final Map<Mechanic, MechanicHandler> mechanics;

    void useAbility(PlayableCharacter source, PlayableCharacter target, Ability ability) {
        source.decreaseResource(ability.getCost());
        for (Effect effect: ability.getEffects()) {
            MechanicHandler mh = mechanics.get(e.getMechanic());
            mh.apply(source, target, effect);
        }
    }

    private static final class DicePerLevel implements MechanicHandler {
        @Override
        public void apply(PlayableCharacter source, PlayableCharacter target, Effect effect) {
            int levels = Math.min(effect.getValue(), source.getLevel());
            int damage = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < levels; ++i) {
                int roll; // roll a d6 die
                damage += roll;
            }
            target.decreaseHealth(damage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like a good approach. What would you recommend to do if I need more flexibility with some abilities. Let's take damage spell for instance, it can get much further than just constants. The damage of "Scorching Rays" can be 3d6 for one scorching ray + another scorching ray for 3 levels above level 3, with maximum amount of 3 rays in total. It can also be just caster level * d6 to a maximum of 10d6. What would you recommend to do ?

Comment: @Niminim I would use a mechanic other than flat damage, in that case, something like `DAMAGE_DICE_PER_LEVEL`. Such mechanic would retrieve the level of `PlayableCharacter source`, roll some dice and multiply the results accordingly. Note that this is just the barebones. If you implement these mechanics in their own methods (or nested classes) they can go as far as you want, if you provide them the state of the game (the attacking character, the target, and so on).

Comment: Can you edit the code with logic for spell that has a damage of 1d6 for each caster level (maximum 10d6)?

Comment: @asfsantos - can you add some logic so I can see an example of the implementation ?

Comment: @Niminim I added an example, using a map and nested classes. In this example the mechanic handler calculates and deals damage equal to 1d6 per character level (max. 10 levels, using the `value` field in the Effect to register the 10).

Comment: Thanks for adding the example :)

Answer (score 3):

The `SpellCaster` spellbook should be a `Map<String, Spell>` so you can look it up by name when it is cast.  The `Spell` class should define an abstract method for applying the effects to a `Character`.  I don't see the point of a "SpellCaster" interface because the implementation of the castSpell() method is always the same (the behavior is delegated to the Spell itself).

Here is a sample scenario:

```
Mage fireMage = new Mage("Red Niminim");
fireMage.addSpell(new Fireball());
fireMage.addAttribute(Attribute.RESIST_FIRE);
fireMage.addAttribute(Attribute.WEAK_TO_COLD);

Mage iceMage = new Mage("Blue Niminim");
fireMage.addSpell(new Icestorm());
fireMage.addAttribute(Attribute.RESIST_COLD);
fireMage.addAttribute(Attribute.WEAK_TO_FIRE);

Cleric cleric = new Cleric("Friar Joe");
cleric.addSpell(new Heal());

// battle!

fireMage.castSpell("Fireball", cleric);     // 15 damage
fireMage.castSpell("Fireball", iceMage);    // 30 damage
fireMage.castSpell("Fireball", fireMage);   // 0 damage

iceMage.castSpell("Icestorm", cleric);      // 15 damage
iceMage.castSpell("Icestorm", fireMage);    // 30 damage
iceMage.castSpell("Icestorm", iceMage);     // 0 damage

cleric.castSpell("Heal", cleric);           // 15 healed
```

Attribute.java

```
public enum Attribute {
    RESIST_FIRE, WEAK_TO_FIRE, RESIST_COLD, WEAK_TO_COLD;
}
```

Spell.java

```
public abstract class Spell {

    private String name;
    private int manaCost;

    public Spell(String name, int manaCost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.manaCost = manaCost;
    }

    public abstract void apply(Character character);

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getManaCost() {
        return manaCost;
    }
}
```

SpellCaster.java (snippet)

```
public void castSpell(String name, Character character) {
    getSpellBook().get(name).apply(character);
}

public void addSpell(Spell spell) {
    getSpellBook().put(spell.getName(), spell);
}
```

Fireball.java

```
public class Fireball extends Spell {

    private static final String NAME = "Fireball";
    private static final int MANA_COST = 8;
    private static final int DAMAGE_AMOUNT = 15;

    public Fireball() {
        super(NAME, MANA_COST);
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(Character character) {
        int damage = DAMAGE_AMOUNT;
        if (character.getAttributes().contains(Attribute.RESIST_FIRE)) {
            damage = 0;
        }
        else if (character.getAttributes().contains(Attribute.WEAK_TO_FIRE)) {
            damage = damage * 2;
        }
        character.setCurrentHp(character.getCurrentHp() - damage);
    }
}
```

Icestorm.java

```
public class Icestorm extends Spell {

    private static final String NAME = "Icestorm";
    private static final int MANA_COST = 8;
    private static final int DAMAGE_AMOUNT = 15;

    public Icestorm() {
        super(NAME, MANA_COST);
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(Character character) {
        int damage = DAMAGE_AMOUNT;
        if (character.getAttributes().contains(Attribute.RESIST_COLD)) {
            damage = 0;
        }
        else if (character.getAttributes().contains(Attribute.WEAK_TO_COLD)) {
            damage = damage * 2;
        }
        character.setCurrentHp(character.getCurrentHp() - damage);
    }
}
```

Heal.java

```
public class Heal extends Spell {

    private static final String NAME = "Heal";
    private static final int MANA_COST = 10;
    private static final int HEAL_AMOUNT = 15; 

    public Heal() {
        super(NAME, MANA_COST);
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(Character character) {
        character.setCurrentHp(character.getCurrentHp() + HEAL_AMOUNT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that would definitely work, but this way I'll have dozens of classes just for spells, which I try to avoid.

Comment: @Niminim I think you will have to put spell behaviour etc. *somewhere* in any case?

Comment: True, but let's say I have DamageSpell class and BuffSpell for instance,  then I don't have to create dozens of classes for each spell, I can just assign the right numbers for each spell. If fireball is a DamageSpell then Fireball(num,num,num,num, num) can do the job, and also for Icestorm( ......), and FireStorm(......) etc.

Comment: @Niminim - this is basically the strategy pattern. The number of classes blows up fast when you do it, but you have to store that information somehow and this is the  cleanest way to do it without putting that information in another class imo. You could take this idea a bit further and make a separate Spellbook project, export it as a JAR, load it into your game, then walla, you have Spell DLC and your game could handle that just fine with this Map approach.

Comment: @Niminim You could alter the granularity of the spell classes, sure.  The key point is the `apply()` method, which is abstract in the `Spell` superclass.

Comment: @JoeCoder Apply/castSpell is definitely the key point here, that's my goal here. I'm not going to have too much subclasses for Spell - DamageSpell, BuffSpell and maybe a few more, that's it.

Comment: Joe, what's your opinion about using the Strategy pattern here ?

Comment: @Niminim I agree with you. This approach will cause you tonnes of classes. So how do game developers avoid this? They use scripting. As for me, I would definitely avoid creating a new class for a new spell. That's just crazy. Imagine tweaking 1 spell, you have to recompile the entire game. I can probably give you my solution tomorrow after I settle my work here.

Comment: @Niminim Your alternative of `DamageSpell` and `BuffSpell` as the only two spell classes will run into limitations quickly.  For example, there is no way to have distinct behavior for `Fireball` and `Icestorm`; if a Character has an immunity to cold, you could not handle this in the `DamageSpell` class.  This would be trivial to implement using a proper Strategy pattern, however.

Comment: @user3437460, I'd like to see your solution tomorrow :) (just keep in mind that I'm a java beginner)

Comment: @Niminim I've updated my example to be more complex (added character attributes), to better illustrate the benefits of using the Strategy pattern

Comment: Nice solution. I'm just intimidated by the amount of classes I can end up this way, it can easily get to do dozens, though it can be easy to handle with the effects of each spell.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how you can use `enum` instead of strings in your `Effects` class. I took the liberty of renaming your `Character` class to `PlayerCharacter` to avoid collision with `java.lang.Character`.

Effects.java:

```
public class Effects {
...
    public static void changeStat(Stat status, int mod, PlayerCharacter target) {
        System.out.println(status + " + " + mod);

        status.effect(mod).accept(target);
    }
}
```

A little bit cleaner, isn't it? How it works? The magic is all in the `enum`:

Stat.java:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator;
import java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer;
import java.util.function.ToIntFunction;

public enum Stat {
    STRENGTH(PlayerCharacter::getStrength, PlayerCharacter::setStrength),
    CONSTITUTION(PlayerCharacter::getConstitution, PlayerCharacter::setStrength),
    DEXTERITY(PlayerCharacter::getDexterity, PlayerCharacter::setDexterity),
    INTELLIGENCE(PlayerCharacter::getIntelligence, PlayerCharacter::setIntelligence),
    WISDOM(PlayerCharacter::getWisdom, PlayerCharacter::setWisdom),
    CHARISMA(PlayerCharacter::getCharisma, PlayerCharacter::setCharisma),
    ARMORCLASS(PlayerCharacter::getArmorClass, PlayerCharacter::setArmorClass);

    Stat(ToIntFunction<PlayerCharacter> findcurrentvalue, ObjIntConsumer<PlayerCharacter> setnewvalue) {
        this.findcurrentvalue = findcurrentvalue;
        this.setnewvalue = setnewvalue;
    }

    private ToIntFunction<PlayerCharacter> findcurrentvalue;
    private ObjIntConsumer<PlayerCharacter> setnewvalue;

    Consumer<PlayerCharacter> effect(int mod) {
        return target -> {
            setnewvalue.accept(target, findcurrentvalue.applyAsInt(target) + mod);
        };
    }
}
```

The two mysterious types [`ToIntFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/ToIntFunction.html) and [`ObjIntConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/ObjIntConsumer.html) are *functional interfaces*:

- `ToIntFunction` takes some kind of object as input (here: a `PlayerCharacter`) and returns an `int`.
- `ObjIntConsumer` takes some kind of object (here: a `PlayerCharacter`) and an `int` as input, and returns nothing.

You could also create your own functional interface if you like, like so:

Effect.java:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Effect<T extends PlayerCharacter> {
    void affect(T t);
}
```

Stat.java:

```
    ...
    Effect<PlayerCharacter> effect(IntUnaryOperator calculator) {
        return target -> {
            setnewvalue.accept(target, calculator.applyAsInt(findcurrentvalue.applyAsInt(target)));
        };
    }
    ...
```

Then you can do this in `changeStat`:

```
public class Effects {
...
    public static void changeStat(Stat status, int mod, PlayerCharacter target) {
        System.out.println(status + " + " + mod);

        status.effect(x -> x + mod).affect(target);
    }
}
```

This way you can decide in the `Effects` class what will happen. Well, I don't imagine the character *stats* to change much from spells, but a similar mechanic can be used for HP and such :)

The `x -> x + mod` bit could come from the spell itself too. It's a function that takes an `int` and returns an `int`, which is called an `IntUnaryOperator` in Java:

Effects.java:

```
...
    public static void boost(int dice, PlayerCharacter target) {
        int value = DiceRoller.roll(dice);
        changeStat(Stat.STRENGTH, x -> x + value, target);
    }

    public static void changeStat(Stat status, IntUnaryOperator change, PlayerCharacter target) {
        status.effect(change).affect(target);
    }
...
```

Here the spell (boost in this case, which I just invented!) will increase the player's strength (the `STRENGTH` constant) by a dice roll. It accomplishes this by calling the `changeStat` with three parameters:

1. `STRENGTH` → tells the method what status to change.
2. A "formula" for changing the value (note that you don't actually need to know the value here, just the formula!).
3. The target to affect.

As you can see, there is no need here to know how to find the strength value, or how to set it to something else. That is all handled by the `enum`, so you can keep your spell code clean.

You could even inline the `changeStat` method directly in the spell method this way, since there isn't really any "real" code in it anymore – that logic is hidden in the `enum`.

Clean and neat :)

Comment: Thanks for the example, Thomas!  The implementation has  some methods and interfaces that I'm not familiar with yet. For a java beginner it looks a bit more complex than I intend my solution to be like.

Comment: I think its interesting that Java 8 has resulted in Java developers using design patterns I haven't seen since C function pointers.

Comment: @JoeCoder As an old C coder myself I know exactly what you mean :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea of having a `SpellCaster` interface (which includes the `castSpell()`) is a good one. This defines the behavior or ability of the character.

I would include the list of available spells as an instance field in the Mage or Cleric classes. Come to think of it, maybe it would be a good idea to create an abstract class called `SpellCaster` which extends `Character`. The `SpellCaster` class can declare the list of spells and subclasses (`Mage` and `Cleric`) can add specific spells to it.

I'm going to discard the `Effects` class for now. Each spell can take care of its own behavior. So for example, when calling `castSpell("spellName", hero, target)` you can pass the required parameters to the spell object and it can take care of dealing the damage or changing stats.

---

In addition, there could be multiple `Spell` subclasses. For example, `DamageSpell`, `Buff`, `Debuff`. The superclass `Spell` has a method `apply()` and each subclass can implement it with it's own behavior. When calling `castSpell()` then you delegate the control to a specific subclass of a `Spell` which has encapsulated the behavior and knows exactly if it should deal damage or change stats. That's essentially [the Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Comment: 1. Spellcaster interface  would can work well here, I'm just not sure how to deal with each spell's effect (it can go complex, because even "damage" can work in different ways). how would you suggest to deal with each spell's effect?  2. Mage and cleric have a spellBook List, that includes all the known (from the whole list). SpellCaster as an abstract class can also work well here, what's the pros and cons of making it abstract class vs. interface ?

Comment: Yeah, I also though about creating few spell classes like  damage spells, buff spells etc. It's good to know that it's a good idea :) . And then Spell should be an abstract class, right ?

Comment: 1. edited answer, you could create multiple subclasses of spells and each one can define it's own behavior. 2. If Mage and Cleric have some common behavior, then this can be placed in the abstract class `SpellCaster`. You can not implement behavior with interfaces.

Comment: Yes, then Spell should be an abstract class.

Comment: Just a thought, if you have other characters who are not spellcasters but can do some spells, then it might be a good idea to use a `SpellCaster` interface. Then it defines the behavior that the character could potentially do.

Comment: Ok. Then I'll make Spell an abstract class with few subclasses. And SpellCaster interface for spellcasters and characters with spell-like abilities..

Comment: I'm sorry to downvote, but there is a lot of bad advice here.  Firstly you don't need `SpellCaster` interface; all spell casters have the exact same behavior for castSpell(), see my answer below.  Also the suggestion to use an interface for spell users called "SpellCasters" for non-`SpellCasters` is confusing and a terrible domain model.

Comment: Joe, it's great that you joined :)

Comment: @JoeCoder good point, in this case the behavior of `castSpell()` is the same, didn't think it fully through

Answer (score 1):

Why treat spells different than abilities? A fighter class might not have spells as magic spells, but it should be able to perform class specific moves like a whirlwind.

Class PlayableCharacter: abstract class, defines the abstract methods for handling resources(regen rate, max, effects on character), abilities, gear. And implements all the basics.

Class ManaCharacter: extends PlayableCharacter handles it resource as mana.

Class Mage extends ManaCharacter: Will just implement the methods to define what kind of gear it can use, the special abilities it can perform, etc.

Comment: "Why treat spells different than abilities? A fighter class might not have spells as magic spells, but it should be able to perform class specific moves like a whirlwind." - I had that in mind, but I haven't started to think about skills and abilities. Your approach sounds good for the long-term.

Comment: How would you deal with Spells (Spells data and casting spells) ?

Comment: Abilities are just methods in the Character classes, no different from `SpellCaster.castSpell()`.  For example, `Fighter.whirlwind()` could be an ability too.